# building ASP.Net core shared framework dlls to output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building a .Net 6.0 library which is being loaded by another application located within an appliance. I have no control over the appliance or the loader app. This library requires references to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework. As this evidentially has not been added to the loader application, I get `could not load assembly` errors for any packages from within the shared framework. Is there any way to force VS2022 to add the required dlls from the framework to the output folder on compile?

`<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` adds the reference dlls to the refs folder but not the runtime dlls required.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the package in the library in VS, try to  set `Include Assets` all .

[image]

Then rebuild and test.

result:

[image]

Comment: This adds a package, not a framework? The tab above the packages within the solution.